# Increase a variable in Less

Tags: less, increment

Is it possible to increase a variable in Less?

```
@i: 0;

.one { border: @i++; }
.two { border: @i++; }
.tree { border: @i++; }
```

or perhaps using mixins in a way, like

```
.increase() {
    @i: @i+1;
    @increase: @i;
}
```

---

To better explain the problem:

```
@icon_width: 32px;

.social{
  background: url('snippet_with_n_images');

  .facebook:   background-position-x: -@icon_width*0;
  .twitter:    background-position-x: -@icon_width*1;
  .googlep:    background-position-x: -@icon_width*2;
  ...
  .pinterest:  background-position-x: -@icon_width*(n-1);
  .linkedin:   background-position-x: -@icon_width*n;

  /*be replaced by */
  .next(): {
     background-position-x: -@icon_width*@i++;
  }
  .facebook:   .next();
  .twitter:    .next();
  .googlep:    .next();
  ...
  .pinterest:  .next();
  .linkedin:   .next();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply speaking, it is not possible to increment the same variable without using a loop (mixin) in Less. This is because Less does lazy loading of variables and so the multiple increments result in recursive definition error. The following snippet:

```css
@i: 0;
.one { @i: @i + 1; border: @i; }
.two { @i: @i + 1; border: @i; }
.three { @i: @i + 1; border: @i; }
```

when compiled would give:

> NameError: Recursive variable definition for @i on line 4, column 7:

Using a mixin like in question (`.increase()`) would still result in the same error as provided above.

---

The best way to increment would be to make use of mixin loops. For the modified sample provided in the question, the loop should be like below:

```css
@icon_width: 32px;
@social-networks: facebook, twitter, googlep, pinterest, linkedin; /* an array with list of networks */
.social{
  background: url('snippet_with_n_images');
  .loop-social(1); /* call loop with initial value as 1 */
}
.loop-social(@index) when (@index < length(@social-networks)){ /* iterate till index is less than array length */
  @social-network: extract(@social-networks, @index); /* extract value corresponding to index from array */
  .@{social-network}{ /* use extracted social network value as selector */
    background-position-x: -@icon_width*@index; /* assign calculated value, the index would incremented for each iteration */
  }
  .loop-social(@index + 1); /* call next iteration with incremented value */
}
```

The above Less code when compiled would produce the following CSS:

```css
.social {
  background: url('snippet_with_n_images');
}
.social .facebook {
  background-position-x: -32px;
}
.social .twitter {
  background-position-x: -64px;
}
.social .googlep {
  background-position-x: -96px;
}
.social .pinterest {
  background-position-x: -128px;
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with loops... could you provide a brief sample?

Comment: @Serge: I have added a sample loop at the end.

Comment: Thanks for this example. I updated the OP to better explain my situation

Comment: I used with comments there are apparently some bugs where to place comments: it loops and puts the comments too in different places! :)

Comment: @Serge: Oops, sorry about that. I just compiled with comments and got the same. I can understand why it puts the comments in the places it does though.